# How to set the GnuPG home directory within the GnuPG Python binding?

Tags: python, gnupg

When trying to initialize the GnuPG binding in Python, I'm getting an error message

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gnupghome'
```

This is the code I'm running:

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:\Users\samss\AppData\Roaming\gnupg')
input_data = gpg.gen_key_input(key_type="RSA",
                           key_length=1024,
                           passphrase='n0sm@sy0')
key =gpg.gen_key(input_data)
print key
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

There are at least 3 different versions of the python gnupg module.  At least 2 of them are in pip.

If you do `pip install gnupg`, you get the older module that uses the homedir argument.

If you do `pip install python-gnupg`, you get a newer module.  In this case, it was the documentation for that module you were reading.

Comment: Brilliant answer - needs more upvotes

Answer (score 4):

There are differnet sources when it comes to documentation, some with homedir, some with gnupghome. I dont know the time they changed it or why.
Some trivial code to provide a solution to OP:

```
import gnupg
print gnupg.__version__
try:
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=homedir) 
except TypeError:
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir=homedir)
```

Please compare the two following tracebacks. Its the same code in both cases. In one case gnupg.GPG expects 'homedir and in the other case 'gnupghome'.
I am working in a virtualenv and have two different distributions of gnupg. 
In the virtualenv python gnupg was installed via pip:

virtualenv:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gnupg
>>> gnupg.__version__
'2.0.2'
>>> homedir=''
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir=homedir)
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=homedir)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gnupghome'
```

global:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gnupg
>>> gnupg.__version__
'0.3.6'
>>> homedir=''
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=homedir)
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir=homedir)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'homedir'
```

I am concerned by the old gnupg version in jessie, though. Can someone elaborate on the matter?

Comment: I actually think they went so far as to backport the change and rerelease. When I uninstalled/reinstalled gnupg 2.3.1 the error suddenly popped up. Insanity! Anyway, this should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to the `gnupg` documentation as it uses `homedir` at the place of `gnupghome`.

Please follow the documentation it might solve your issues: [gnupg python documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/gnupg/gnupg.html)

Comment: To be fair older versions did use `gnupghome` and its in older versions of the documentation. I got bit by this too when upgrading an older script

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG (as command line tool) knows two ways to specify the GnuPG home directory:

1. Using an environment variable:

   ```
   GPGHOME=C:\Users\samss\AppData\Roaming\gnupg gpg
   ```
2. Passing it as a parameter (which is also available as `homedir` parameter in the configuration file):

   ```
   gpg --homedir=C:\Users\samss\AppData\Roaming\gnupg
   ```

The [GnuPG Python binding](https://pythonhosted.org/gnupg/gnupg.html) allows some *parameters* to be passed during initialization. Because of the initialization syntax, you probably mixed this up with the environment variable version of defining the home directory on the command line.

An additional warning: You probably want to access another system user's GnuPG home directory. GnuPG is *very* picky about safe permissions. For a development machine, it might be fine to use the GnuPG parameter `--no-permission-warning` and privileges that allow rather broad access, but better start with a clean approach from the start and initialize a new GnuPG home directory for your application that can be properly restricted regarding permissions.

Comment: Setting `GNUPGHOME` env. variable makes problems... (Windows OS).