# Decrypting .pgp to .txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnupg

In the code below, please suggest why is there this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gnupghome'
```

It's the same as example code in [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started):

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/path/to/home/directory')
```

Comment: That error message is different to the code you're showing.

Comment: I just changed the file name from '/home/tester' to '/path/to/home/directory'
Error stays the same,

Comment: No, you have invalid syntax in the question `''` is not the same as `"`.

Comment: What version of `gnupg` are you using?

Comment: See this identical question: [How to set the GnuPG home directory within the GnuPG Python binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028852/how-to-set-the-gnupg-home-directory-within-the-gnupg-python-binding)

Comment: `'` *is* the same as `"`.. isn't it? I mean, in all respects besides having to escape their opposites.

Comment: @PeterWood  gnupg version: 2.2.0

Comment: 'homedir' instead of 'gnupghome' - worked

Comment: @Julien I've fixed it, but `''Julien''` is not the same as `"Julien"`, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize that you actually typed two `''` characters, my apologies :)